# How to update id from Temp table to Actual Table

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two table, `Temp_Table` and `Actual_Table`. I upload csv file that only contain field `home_id` for the first time and will insert to `Temp_Table` then insert to `Actual_Table`. Field `id` is auto incremented and `home_run` is field that will generate after user input process.

This is the code i use to generate `home_run` based on `home_id` then insert to actual table.

```
$query1 = "UPDATE Temp_Table AS p JOIN (
                 SELECT t.id,(SELECT count(*) FROM Temp_Table 
                 WHERE home_id = t.home_id AND id <= t.id) AS home_run FROM Temp_Table t) 
                 AS g ON p.id = g.id SET p.home_id = g.home_id";

$query2 = "INSERT INTO Actual_Table (home_id, home_run) SELECT (home_id, home_run) FROM Temp_Table";

$query3 = "SELECT MAX(home_run) FROM Actual_Table GROUP BY home_id";
```

This is example of data in Actual_Table after first time i upload the csv file.

`Data in Actual_Table (Table 1)`

```
+---------------------------+
|id  |  home_id  | home_run |
|1   |    H01    |    1     |
|2   |    H01    |    2     |
|3   |    H01    |    3     |
|4   |    H02    |    1     |
+---------------------------+
```

Let say, i upload csv file for second time and this is the data in Temp_Table.

`Example Data in Temp_Table (Table 2)`

```
+---------------------------+
|id  |  home_id  | home_run |
|1   |    H01    |    1     |
|2   |    H01    |    2     |
|3   |    H02    |    1     |
+---------------------------+
```

I need to insert value from `Temp_Table` to `Actual_Table` and continuously count the `home_run`. Example from the `Table 1`, i get the highest home_run for each id. `H01 = 3`, `H02 = 1`.

So i plan to do calculation based on home_id: (Highest home_run) `3` + (Temp_Table home_run) `x`.  `x is 1 and 2 for H01` and `x is 1 for H02`.

At the end, the `Actual_Table` will be like this

`ORDER BY id`

```
+---------------------------+
|id  |  home_id  | home_run |
|1   |    H01    |    1     |
|2   |    H01    |    2     |
|3   |    H01    |    3     |
|4   |    H02    |    1     |
|5   |    H01    |    4     |
|6   |    H01    |    5     |
|7   |    H02    |    2     |
+---------------------------+
```

`ORDER BY home_run`

```
+---------------------------+
|id  |  home_id  | home_run |
|1   |    H01    |    1     |
|2   |    H01    |    2     |
|3   |    H01    |    3     |
|5   |    H01    |    4     |
|6   |    H01    |    5     |
|4   |    H02    |    1     |
|7   |    H02    |    2     |
+---------------------------+
```

It is possible to do this? I am stuck and do not have idea to create the query for the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Below are my ways of achieving this but I'm sure there are better solutions out there.

1st of all, get the **maximum** ID out of actual table  *(Mark as A)*:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM Actual_Table
```

Then, get the **maximum** home_run of each home_id  *(Mark as B)*:

```
SELECT MAX(home_run) FROM Actual_Table Group By home_id
```

Finally, join them together into a **SELECT** statement:

```
SELECT MAX(A.id) + T.id, T.home_id, T.home_run + MAX(B.home_run)
  FROM Temp_Table T, Actual_Table A, Actual_Table B
 WHERE T.home_id = B.home_id
 GROUP BY T.id, T.home_id, T.home_run
```

The rest is just simply changing the **SELECT** statement into **INSERT** statement.

```
INSERT INTO Actual_Table
SELECT MAX(A.id) + T.id, T.home_id, T.home_run + MAX(B.home_run)
  FROM Temp_Table T, Actual_Table A, Actual_Table B
 WHERE T.home_id = B.home_id
 GROUP BY T.id, T.home_id, T.home_run
```